# Courier New monospace font not found by fontspec in Overleaf?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, overleaf

I'm trying to use the `Courier New` font via `setmonofont` and the `fontspec` package, but for some reason, Overleaf relentlessly states that the font is unavailable. I cannot use the `courier` package because I must compile my project with XeLaTeX. The output PDF only shows the `This is not Courier font`; the `This is Courier font` is not present.

preamble.tex:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry {
    paperheight=9.1in,paperwidth=6.1in,
    top=1in,bottom=1in,right=0.5in,left=0.5in
}
% to be loaded first in order to avoid conflicts
\usepackage{prooftrees}
\usepackage{amsthm}

% fonts
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[
  %varvw,
]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{pifont}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
% \setmonofont{}

% math or related
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{simplebnf}
\usepackage{forest}

% typesetting
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{framed}% <- really?
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{syntax}% <- really?
\usepackage[super]{nth}
```

main.tex:

```
\include{preamble.tex}

\begin{document}
This is not Courier font. \texttt{This is Courier font.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your example produces `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package fontspec.
`

Comment: Courier New is proprietary, isn't it? I doubt Overleaf has it available unless you uploaded it yourself.